# Android, Location Request, set expiration duration doesn't work

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I'm using new API of location which had been introduced in I/O 2013.

It works fine and I have no problem with its results. My problem is when I set `setExpirationDuration(WHATEVER_MILLIS)` to whatever millis however it works for one minutes.

This is my code:

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                            .setInterval(10 * 60 * 1000) // every 10 minutes
                            .setExpirationDuration(10 * 1000) // After 10 seconds
                            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

When I run the app, satellite indicator will be displayed in tray so, I expect to see it just 10 seconds. However, it will be disappear after a minute.

Any suggestion or comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the interval time is divided by the expiry time leaving 1 minute

Comment: Thanks JRowan, no matter what I set as milli satellite indicator will be displayed for a minute.

Comment: Do you think maybe its the priority high accuracy, gps takes a bit to home in on an exact location, maybe overriding the expiry

Comment: Based on what Google mentioned in its doc page (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setExpirationDuration(long)), "The location client will automatically stop updates after the request expires.". So, have no idea why it doesn't stop. But defiantly you are right. I'm in covered area. But this method should stop it. Even  setExpirationTime (long millis) method doesn't work as well ;(

Comment: I read the link , what is the elapsedrealtime it says it is included, maybe add 10 seconds to the interval it says you can set a time less than the elapsedrealtime and maybe 1 minute is the default for that since it wouldn't make sense

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Sometimes it is just one minute, sometimes it is much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to be a real problem in Android, a workaround could be a Handler to remove location updates manually.

```
    listHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(MyActivity.this);
                //Location Updates are now removed
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
```

After you request for location updates (for a maximum duration of 10s) you call this Handler, of course delayed for 10s.

```
myLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(...);
listHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 10000);
```

This makes sure, that after 10s your location updates are removed.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setExpirationDuration(long))

It says that: 
*"The duration begins immediately (and not when the request is passed to the location client), so call this method again if the request is re-used at a later time."*

One would expect this duration to start when following line is called:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, request, this);
```

But, documentation states this duration begins when request object is created.